# Всегда выполняется условие при проверке базы данных sql

Tags: python, sql, tkinter, if

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox  
import os
import sqlite3

db=sqlite3.connect('server.db')
sql = db.cursor()

destroy_obj = []
#def EditWorkers(event, pasport):
    #sql.execute("UPDATE users SET * = '{}'")
    
def CheckChange(name):
    if name.get() == 1 : x = "yes"
    else : x = "no"
    return x 
def Destroy_object():
    for x in destroy_obj:
        x.destroy()
def Save_worker(event , name_addw , salary_addw, pasport_addw, position_addw, priorety_addw, sun_m_addw , sun_e_addw, mon_m_addw , mon_e_addw , tue_m_addw, tue_e_addw , wed_m_addw , wed_e_addw , thu_m_addw, thu_e_addw, fri_m_addw , sat_e_addw):
    sql.execute(""" CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
        name TEXT,
        salary BIGINT,
        pasport TEXT,
        position TEXT,
        priorety TEXT, 
        sunday_morning TEXT,
        sunday_evenyng TEXT,
        monday_morning TEXT,
        monday_evenyng TEXT,
        tuesday_morning TEXT,
        tuesday_evenyng TEXT,
        wednesday_morning TEXT,
        wednesday_evenyng TEXT,
        thursday_morning TEXT,
        thursday_evenyng TEXT,
        friday_morning TEXT,
        satyrday_evenyng TEXT
    
    
    ) """)
    db.commit()
    sql.execute("SELECT pasport FROM users WHERE pasport = '{pasport_addw.get()}'")
    if sql.fetchone() is None :
#Условие всегда выполняется  <<<---------- 
        sql.execute("INSERT INTO users (name, salary ,pasport,priorety, position, sunday_morning, sunday_evenyng, monday_morning , monday_evenyng, tuesday_morning , tuesday_evenyng , wednesday_morning , wednesday_evenyng, thursday_morning, thursday_evenyng ,friday_morning , satyrday_evenyng) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ,? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? ,? ,?)" ,(
            name_addw.get() ,
            salary_addw.get(),
            pasport_addw.get() ,
            position_addw.get(),
            priorety_addw.get(),
            CheckChange(sun_m_addw),
            CheckChange(sun_e_addw),
            CheckChange(mon_m_addw),
            CheckChange(mon_e_addw) ,
            CheckChange(tue_m_addw),
            CheckChange(tue_e_addw) ,
            CheckChange(wed_m_addw) ,
            CheckChange(wed_e_addw) ,
            CheckChange(thu_m_addw) ,
            CheckChange(thu_e_addw) ,
            CheckChange(fri_m_addw) ,
            CheckChange(sat_e_addw) ))
        db.commit()
        #save_savew = Label(text = "name {0} , salary {1} , pasport {2} ,position {3} , priorety {4}\n days of work\n  Sunday : morning - {5} , evenyng - {6} \n Monday : morning - {7} , evenyng - {8} \n Tuesday : morning - {9} , evenyng - {10} \n Wednesday : morning - {11} , evenyng - {12} \n Thursday: morning - {13} , evenyng - {14} \n Friday : morning - {15} \n Saturday : evenyng - {16} \n SAVED ".format(*sql.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE pasport = '{pasport_addw.get()}'")))
            #name_addw.get() ,
            #salary_addw.get(),
            #pasport_addw.get() ,
            #position_addw.get(),
            #priorety_addw.get(),
            #CheckChange(sun_m_addw),
            #CheckChange(sun_e_addw),
            #CheckChange(mon_m_addw),
            #CheckChange(mon_e_addw) ,
            #CheckChange(tue_m_addw),
            #CheckChange(tue_e_addw) ,
            #CheckChange(wed_m_addw) ,
            #CheckChange(wed_e_addw) ,
            #CheckChange(thu_m_addw) ,
            #CheckChange(thu_e_addw) ,
            #CheckChange(fri_m_addw) ,
            #CheckChange(sat_e_addw)) )
        #save_savew.grid(row = 12 , column = 0 )
        #destroy_obj.append(save_savew)
    else :
        justcr_savew = Label(text = "pasport {0} just created".format(pasport_addw.get()) )
        justcr_savew.grid(row = 12 , column = 0)
        destroy_obj.append(justcr_savew)
def Add_worker():
    Destroy_object()
#Entry
    name1_addw = Label (text = "Name")
    salary1_addw = Label (text = "Salary")
    pasport1_addw = Label (text = "Pasport")
    pasport_addw = Entry()
    name_addw = Entry()
    salary_addw = Entry()
    position1_addw = Label(text = "Position")
    position_addw = Combobox()
    position_addw['values'] = ('manager' , 'worker')
    priorety1_addw = Label(text = "Priorety")
    priorety_addw = Combobox()
    priorety_addw['values'] = (1,2,3)
    
#Checkbutton
    sun_m_addw1 = IntVar()
    sun_m_addw = Checkbutton(text = "Sunday morning" , onvalue = 1 , offvalue = 0 , variable=sun_m_addw1 )
    sun_e_addw1 = IntVar()
    sun_e_addw = Checkbutton(text = "Sunday evenyng" , onvalue = 1 , offvalue = 0 , variable=sun_e_addw1 )
    mon_m_addw1 = IntVar()
    mon_m_addw = Checkbutton(text = "Monday morning" , onvalue = 1 , offvalue = 0 , variable=mon_m_addw1 )
    mon_e_addw1 = IntVar()
    mon_e_addw = Checkbutton(text = "Monday evenyng" , onvalue = 1 , offvalue = 0 , variable=mon_e_addw1)
    tue_m_addw1 = IntVar()
    tue_m_addw = Checkbutton(text = "Tuesday morning" , onvalue = 1 , offvalue = 0 ,variable=tue_m_addw1 )
    tue_e_addw1 = IntVar()
    tue_e_addw = Checkbutton(text = "Tuesday evenyng" , onvalue = 1 , offvalue = 0 , variable=tue_e_addw1)
    wed_m_addw1 = IntVar()
    wed_m_addw = Checkbutton(text = "Wednesday morning" , onvalue = 1 , offvalue = 0, variable=wed_m_addw1 )
    wed_e_addw1 = IntVar()
    wed_e_addw = Checkbutton(text = "Wednesday evenyng" , onvalue = 1 , offvalue = 0 ,variable=wed_e_addw1)
    thu_m_addw1 = IntVar()
    thu_m_addw = Checkbutton(text = "Thursday morning" , onvalue = 1 , offvalue = 0 ,variable=thu_m_addw1)
    thu_e_addw1 = IntVar()
    thu_e_addw = Checkbutton(text = "Thursday evenyng" , onvalue = 1 , offvalue = 0,variable=thu_e_addw1)
    fri_m_addw1 = IntVar()
    fri_m_addw = Checkbutton(text = "Friday morning" , onvalue = 1 , offvalue = 0,variable=fri_m_addw1 )
    sat_e_addw1 = IntVar()
    sat_e_addw = Checkbutton(text = "Saturday evenyng" , onvalue = 1 , offvalue = 0 ,variable=sat_e_addw1)
#Button
    add_addw = Button (text = "ADD WORKER")
    add_addw.bind ("<Button-1>" , lambda btn,
                   n_a=name_addw,
                   s_a=salary_addw ,
                   p_a = pasport_addw,
                   po_a = position_addw,
                   pr_a = priorety_addw,
                   su_a_m = sun_m_addw1 ,
                   su_a_e = sun_e_addw1 ,
                   mo_a_e = mon_m_addw1,
                   mo_a_m = mon_e_addw1,
                   tu_a_m = tue_m_addw1,
                   tu_a_e = tue_e_addw1,
                   we_a_m = wed_m_addw1,
                   we_a_e = wed_e_addw1,
                   th_a_m = thu_m_addw1,
                   th_a_e = thu_e_addw1,
                   fr_a_m = fri_m_addw1,
                   sa_a_e = sat_e_addw1:
                   Save_worker(btn, n_a, s_a, p_a, po_a, pr_a, su_a_m , su_a_e , mo_a_m , mo_a_e , tu_a_m , tu_a_e , we_a_m, we_a_e, th_a_m , th_a_e , fr_a_m , sa_a_e))
#Grid
    name_addw.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
    salary_addw.grid(row = 1 , column = 1)
    name1_addw.grid(row = 0 , column = 0)
    salary1_addw.grid(row = 1 , column = 0)
    pasport1_addw.grid(row = 2 , column = 0)
    pasport_addw.grid(row = 2 , column = 1 )
    add_addw.grid(row = 5, column = 0 )
    position1_addw.grid(row = 3 , column = 0)
    position_addw.grid(row = 3 , column = 1)
    priorety1_addw.grid(row = 4 , column = 0)
    priorety_addw.grid(row = 4 , column = 1)
    sun_m_addw.grid(row = 0 , column = 2)
    sun_e_addw.grid(row = 1 , column = 2)
    mon_m_addw.grid(row = 2 , column = 2)
    mon_e_addw.grid(row = 3 , column = 2)
    tue_m_addw.grid(row = 4 , column = 2)
    tue_e_addw.grid(row = 5 , column = 2)
    wed_m_addw.grid(row = 6 , column = 2)
    wed_e_addw.grid(row = 7 , column = 2)
    thu_m_addw.grid(row = 8 , column = 2)
    thu_e_addw.grid(row = 9 , column = 2)
    fri_m_addw.grid(row = 10 , column = 2)
    sat_e_addw.grid(row = 11 , column = 2)
#Destroy
    destroy_obj.append(pasport1_addw)
    destroy_obj.append(pasport_addw)
    destroy_obj.append(add_addw)
    destroy_obj.append(name1_addw)
    destroy_obj.append(salary1_addw)
    destroy_obj.append(name_addw)
    destroy_obj.append(salary_addw)
    destroy_obj.append(position1_addw)
    destroy_obj.append(position_addw)
    destroy_obj.append(priorety1_addw)
    destroy_obj.append(priorety_addw)
    destroy_obj.append(sun_m_addw)
    destroy_obj.append(sun_e_addw)
    destroy_obj.append(mon_m_addw)
    destroy_obj.append(mon_e_addw)
    destroy_obj.append(tue_m_addw)
    destroy_obj.append(tue_e_addw)
    destroy_obj.append(wed_m_addw)
    destroy_obj.append(wed_e_addw)
    destroy_obj.append(thu_m_addw)
    destroy_obj.append(thu_e_addw)
    destroy_obj.append(fri_m_addw)
    destroy_obj.append(sat_e_addw)
def Worker_list():
    Destroy_object()
    a_worl = ('name', 'salary' ,'pasport','priorety', 'position', 'sunday_m', 'sunday_e', 'monday_m' , 'monday_e', 'tuesday_m' , 'tuesday_e' , 'wednesday_m' , 'wednesday_e', 'thursday_m', 'thursday_e' ,'friday_m' , 'satyrday_e')
    for w,q in enumerate (a_worl):
        globals()['y{0}_worl'.format(w)] = Label(text = q)
        globals()['y{0}_worl'.format(w)].grid(row = 0 , column = w)
        destroy_obj.append(globals()['y{0}_worl'.format(w)])
    for x ,y  in enumerate (sql.execute("SELECT * FROM users")):
        for i,b  in enumerate (y) :
            globals()['x{0}{1}_worl'.format(x,i)]= Label(text = b)
            globals()['x{0}{1}_worl'.format(x,i)].grid(row = x+1 , column = i)
            destroy_obj.append(globals()['x{0}{1}_worl'.format(x,i)])
        globals()['xr{0}_worl'.format(x)] = Label(text = "Edit")
        globals()['xr{0}_worl'.format(x)].grid(row = x+1 , column = len(y) )
        globals()['xd{0}_worl'.format(x)] = Label(text = "Delete")
        globals()['xd{0}_worl'.format(x)].grid(row = x+1 , column = (len(y)+1))
        destroy_obj.append(globals()['xr{0}_worl'.format(x)])
        destroy_obj.append(globals()['xd{0}_worl'.format(x)])
            

root= Tk()
filemenu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=filemenu)
filemenu.add_command(label = "Add worker" , command = Add_worker)
filemenu.add_command(label = "Worker list" , command = Worker_list)
filemenu.add_command(label = "Schedule")
root.mainloop()
```

При проверке номера паспорта , в случае если он уже есть в базе данных , программа должна выдавать что такой пользователь уже в базе , вместо этого идёт повторная регистрация. Что делать ?

Comment: *#Условие всегда выполняется* Вы забавный... только что создали таблицу, тут же делаете в неё запрос, и при этом удивляетесь, что ни фига не возвращается... да пустая она, пустая! сперва сделайте в неё хотя бы один INSERT...

Comment: У меня в таблице уже 10 позиций есть . У меня нет вопросов , если условие выполняется при 1 вводе , проблема что оно выполняется если в таблице уже есть такая позиция

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так

```
sql.execute("SELECT pasport FROM users WHERE pasport = '{pasport_addw.get()}'")
if len(sql.fetchall()[0]) == 0 :
```

Comment: if len(sql.fetchall()[0]) == 0 :
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]